# Migrate smooth streaming encoded video files to Azure Media Service

Tags: windows, streaming, smoothing, azure-media-services

My company streams videos using IIS Media Services to Silverlight players, the streams are delivered as adaptive bitrates (Microsoft Smooth Streaming). Due to support for Silverlight plugin being dropped by all major browsers, we are planning to migrate our streaming platform to Azure.

I have checked the documentations, samples & read articles and couldn't find anything on how to use existing smooth streaming encoded video without having to re-encode. We have quite a large asset to migrate, around 400GB, re-encoding is not an option, also we plan to dynamically encrypt our content using AES. Does anyone know how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform following steps

1. Create azure media services asset
2. Upload files for specified asset.
3. Then you need to run media encryptor encoder "Windows Azure Media Encryptor"
4. Configure delivery options

See https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-media-services/blob/dev/test/net/Scenario/JobTests.cs.

Method

```
private IAsset CreateSmoothAsset()
```

covering step 1&2.
There are various tests in this file to cover encrypting asset using "Windows Azure Media Encryptor" encoder(see usage of

```
GetMediaProcessor(_mediaContext, WindowsAzureMediaServicesTestConfiguration.MpEncryptorName);
```

)

To configure delivery of  protected content see - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-protect-with-aes128/ .

There is also media processor called "Windows Azure Media Packager" which will allow you to package your smooth asset for example to HLS.

Comment: Thanks for your response, the videos being imported to AMS are VC-1 Advance encoded smooth streaming, I read from a few sources that only H.264 encoded smooth streaming files are supported for dynamic package in AMS. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

You can onboard your existing Smooth streaming assets to Azure Media Services without re-encoding them and apply dynamic encryption of AES and dynamic packaging to different streaming formats such as HLS, MPEG-DASH and Smooth Streaming. However, there can be some limitations and constrains. If your content is already encrypted such as Smooth Streaming + PlayReady it is not supported to dynamic encrypt to AES. Your content needs to be in clear form if you want to use dynamic encryption. Also your Smooth Streaming assets needs to be Smooth Streaming spec complaint. There are tools which generates Smooth Streaming files which is not spec complaint and not supported by Azure Media Services.
You can use creating assets from existing storage blobs article to start 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-copying-existing-blob/

I hope this answers your question.
Cenk

Comment: I have successfully uploaded the smoothing streaming files to storage account that is associated with the Media Services account I created. I added one streaming unit. The problem now is that I'm getting "a network error caused the video download to fail part-way" when I tried to play the asset using the media services player. Could this be an issue files?